# If R1 and R2 are total order, is R total order?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

Let $(A,R_1)$, $(B,R_2)$ be two posets. Then, *$R$ is defined by*-$\{(a,b)R(x,y)$ if $aR_1x$ and $bR_2y \}$ *is a partial order*.

Using this statement, can we say that *if $R_1$ and $R_2$ are total orders then, R is a total order?*

My book has the following answer however, I think it's wrong.
[image: answer]

This is why I think its wrong-
it says we cannot compare $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$. This means that $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ must be in the relationship $R$. If such is the case then, $1R_12$(Does exist in $R$) and $2R_21$(Does not exist $R$).
(basically, what I am trying to say is that we could have made this argument if $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ belonged to the relation $R$ but since they don't($2 !< 1$) we can't make this argument, (it is failing $2R_21)$)

The original question is as follows in my book(question 4)
[image: book]

Comment: what is $x$ in your first line

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: @Shaun Really Sorry, have a test tomorrow, will take care next time.

Comment: @Mihail I have edited, sorry had made a typo, you may refer to the original question from the book

Comment: Well, since $R_1$ and $R_2$ are given as "is less than and equal to" relation, $1 R_1 2$ is incorrect, so with respect to the order $R$ you cannot say $(1,2) R (2,1)$ or $(2,1) R (1,2).$ This means that $R$ is not a total order defined on your sets.

Comment: @Motun but since 1 <= 2, 1R<sub>1</sub>2 is correct

Comment: Well, I cannot read what you exactly wrote there but, in case $(2,1) R(1,2)$, we need $1 R_2 2$ which is the same as $1 R_1 2$ by definition. You need to preserve the orders on both components of the tuple $(1,2)$ and $(2,1).$ ( I think I wrote the orders in the wrong order, but if $1 R_1 2$ is true, then $2 R_1 1$ is not true so the argument can be corrected).

Comment: @Motun I mean the process that I am thinking about goes as follows- 
total order means any two elements I pick must be comparable, either xRy or yRx
So, here R1 can be {(1,1), (2,2), (1,2)} and same with R2 in order to be partial order and total order.
So, here, I can have R as- {(1,1)R(1,1), (2,2)R(2,2), (1,1)R(2,2), (1,2)R(1,2)} and that's it I guess, not sure.

Comment: Do you want me to add solution to the question 3 of the problem if that will be any helpful. I don't know...

Comment: Oh I think I got it,  R will be - {(1,1)R(1,1), (2,2)R(2,2), (1,1)R(2,2), (1,2)R(1,2), (2,1)R(2,1),...}
focussing on the two elements- (1,2)R(1,2) and (2,1)R(2,1), total order says they must be comparable but, (1,2)!R(2,1) since 2 !≤ 1.

Comment: That should be right ig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with relations $R_1$ and $R_2$ on $A$ and $B$ respectively, we define  the relation $R$ on $A\times B$ by:
$$\forall x_1,x_2\in A:\text{ }\forall y_1,y_2\in B:\bigg[(x_1,y_1)\color{red}{R}(x_2,y_2)\leftrightarrow \big((x_1\color{red}{R_1}x_2)\wedge (y_1\color{red}{R_2}y_2)\big)\bigg].$$

---

It is straight forward to check that the *Reflexive, Antisymmetric, and Transitive* properties of a *Partial Order* follow from both $R_i$'s having that property. This is the content of question **(3)**.

For question **(4)**, consider the following diagram for arbitrary $x_1,x_2\in A\text{ and }y_1,y_2\in B$
$\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }$
[image]

The Reflexive Property gives us the dual **black** arrows and the $\color{darkred}{\text{red}}$ and $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ arrows are one sided possibilities for the component relations (Anti-Symmetry causes the one-sidedness, unless the elements are equal). So there are cases to consider here.

---

$\underline{If\text{ } x_1 = x_2\text{ and }y_1=y_2:}$
Then the red and blue arrows become double sided and Transitivity allows us to connect $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ in both directions. Hence in this case, they are comparable.
$\underline{\text{Else If } x_1 \neq x_2\text{ and }y_1=y_2:}$
The equality collapses the blue arrows and Transitivity gives us one-directional comparability of $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ (depending on the option for red).
$\underline{\text{Else If } x_1 = x_2\text{ and }y_1\neq y_2:}$
Similarly, we get one directional comparability of $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ (dependent on blue's option).
$\underline{\text{Else If }\text{ } x_1 \neq x_2\text{ and }y_1\neq y_2:}$
Both red and blue arrows have options for 1-sidedness. In the event that the arrows line up, Transitivity gives us 1-d comparability. In the other event, when arrows conflict, we are not guaranteed an arrow in $R$ by Transitivity, though this diagonal arrow from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$ may or may not exist in the relation independently without contradiction. $\color{orange}{\text{In this case, comparability is not guaranteed. Begins hunt for counter-example...}}$

---

...Finds the books counter example is also labeled **4.** With $R_i := "\leq"$, and $A,B:=\{1,2\}$, notice $(x_1,y_1) := (1,2)$ and $(x_2,y_2) := (2,1)$ fall in our latter case. We investigate the existence of the diagonal arrows, given our particular knowledge of how $"\leq"$ works. We come up with the diagram:
$\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }$[image]
and deduce that since the $\color{gold}{\text{gold}}$ component arrows go in opposite directions, the desired arrow in $R$ does not exist. 
Finally, this gives us a c.x. where $R_i$'s may be total, but $R$ is not. $[\times]$

Comment: Or you can just draw the Hasse diagram for that product and see that the product of two (nontrivial, i.e., each with more than one element) total orders is not a total order.

Comment: @amrsa yes, I could do that.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks a lot :) , this answer is just perfect